# Delete characters before the third slash

Tags: php, regex

I just want to delete all characters before the third slash.

Example:

```
C:/wamp/www/project/modules/File

becomes:

project/modules/File
```

I'll appreciate help. Thanks.

Comment: We do not care what you want. Tell us what you have tried and then formulate a question that we can answer.

Comment: Is C:/wamp/www/ remains same for all such strings ?

Comment: Sverri M. Olsen, you may know what I'm asking by reading my post. Is that the way you get extra rep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One elegant solution comes to my mind is :

```
$text = "C:/wamp/www/project/modules/File";

$arr = explode("/", $text);
//shifting array three times, increase if necessary
array_shift($arr);array_shift($arr);array_shift($arr);
//implode and return
return implode("/", $arr);
```

Plain and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code i hope this will help you.

```
$str = "C:/wamp/www/project/modules/File";
$positions = mb_stripos_all($str,"/");
echo substr($str,$positions[2]+1);
function mb_stripos_all($haystack, $needle) {

  $s = 0;
  $i = 0;

  while(is_integer($i)) {

    $i = strpos($haystack, $needle, $s);

    if(is_integer($i)) {
      $aStrPos[] = $i;
      $s = $i + strlen($needle);
    }
  }

  if(isset($aStrPos)) {
    return $aStrPos;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$str = 'C:/wamp/www/project/modules/File';
if (preg_match('%.*?/.*?/.*?/(.*)%', $str, $regs)) {
    $str = $regs[1];
}
echo $str;
?>

Result: project/modules/File
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text="C:/wamp/www/project/modules/File";
$pieces = explode("/", $text);
$i=0;
foreach ($pieces as $valor) {
$i++;
if($i>3)
    echo $valor.'/';
}
```

return

> `project/modules/File/`

Answer (score 0):

```
$text="C:/wamp/www/project/modules/File";
$pieces = explode("/", $text);

 $len=sizeof($pieces);
 for($i=3;$i<$len; $i++)
 {
    $path.=$pieces[$i]."/";
 }

$path1 = substr($path, 0, -1);
 echo $path1;

 I think this will print how long contents after file..
 try it...
```